# How to get collections in path using pattern matching?

Tags: coffeescript, docpad, backbone-model, query-engine

```
collections:
    posts: ->
        # @getCollection('documents').findAllLive({relativeDirPath: 'posts'}, [date: -1])
        @getCollection('documents').findAllLive({relativeDirPath: {'$in' : ['posts', /post\/[0-9]+/ ]}}, [date: -1])
```

In the main `docpad.coffee`, `{relativeDirPath: {'$in' : ['posts']}` is the standard thing to do.

However, `{relativeDirPath: {'$in' : ['posts', /post\/[0-9]+/ ]}` does not.

I am trying to get files that are in the following directory structure to be added to the `posts` collection:

```
/src/documents/posts/blah-blah.html
/src/documents/post/12345678/foo-bar-baz.html
/src/documents/post/62347878/woop-woop.html
```

... and using pattern matching in `relativeDirPath` seems to be the way to go.
However, it does not match any of those files.
How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the requirement, you don't need pattern matching. The group query key "$or" should work for you:

```
@getCollection('documents').findAllLive
    $or: [
            {
                relativeDirPath:
                    "$startsWith": "posts"
            }
            {
                relativeDirPath:
                    "$startsWith": "post"
            }
        ]
, [date: -1]
```